# Getting some data from a webpage using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wanted to get some data from a [url page](https://scan.coredao.org/token/0x0e6a77f87beb332e5fe1d1241fc8d49b8c9833b3). I have some code below but I cannot get it to run properly to provide the output I need.

Any idea will be very helpful.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0"}
urllink = "https://scan.coredao.org/token/0x7c6a914cb866654b50f94e66b80c046dd9225ba9"
print ("urllink: ", urllink)

urlpage = requests.get(urllink, headers=headers, timeout=5)
print ("urlpage: ", urlpage)

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlpage.content, 'html.parser')
supply = soup.find('div', class_='el-row power-description mb-4').get_text()
print ("supply: ", supply)
```

Data needed:

```
Total Supply: 2,100,000,000 CAKE       Contract: 0x7c6a914cb866654b50f94e66b80c046dd9225ba9
Holders:      9,299                    Decimals: 18
Transfers:    21,421                   Official Site: https://cakecore.io
Social Profiles:
    coreteam@cakecore.io
    https://cakecore.io/whitepaper
    https://t.me/cakecore_io
    https://twitter.com/cakecore_io
```

My output:

```
urllink:  https://scan.coredao.org/token/0x7c6a914cb866654b50f94e66b80c046dd9225ba9
urlpage:  <Response [200]>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/estorbotz/Desktop/Personal Files/CORE/Temp - Get Token Info V1.py", line 23, in <module>
    supply = soup.find('div', class_='el-row power-description mb-4').get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you state what you expect in your result along with what you are actually getting.

Comment: If I had to guess the issue is with the webpage that seems to load the content afterwards. (SPA behaviour). So I think it would be easyer to use [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) that BeautifulSoup

Comment: @ShadowCrafter_01 looks like that is the case. Blocking scripts results in a page with no content. OP will likely need a javascript executor to dynamically load the content back

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be occurring because the website you are trying to access is using JavaScript to render page content. The request library does not execute JavaScript, it just downloads the HTML code of the page.

In this case, a possible solution is to use a library that executes JavaScript, such as Selenium. With Selenium, you can control a web browser to access a page and get the HTML code rendered.

Here is an example of how to use Selenium to access the website and get the HTML code rendered:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = Options()
options.headless = True

service = Service('path/to/chomerdriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)


urllink = "https://scan.coredao.org/token/0x7c6a914cb866654b50f94e66b80c046dd9225ba9"
driver.get(urllink)

html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
supply = soup.find('div', class_="flex items-center")

print("supply: ", supply)

driver.quit()
```

the problem is that even when rendering the js there is a script that hides the token values, and renders them later, I believe that the objective is precisely to block the use of for webscripting